# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1-|\!\sin n|}$convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

As in the title, is the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+|\!\sin(n)|}}
$$
convergent or not? This is a variant of a simpler exercise in a first year curse in analysis, so I don't know if there is a simple answer (in any case wasn't able to find one).

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question! I didn't see it.

Comment: No need to be sorry, it's a good question!